# Whole app in MEAN stack crashes for a single bug

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack

I am developing a web application using MEAN stack. When an error comes in the codes, the whole application crashes and I have to restart the server (re-run the application).

This behavior may not be a problem during development. But when the application goes to production, and if some unexpected errors occurs, the whole application will crash. I have to keep an eye on the system constantly and restart it when an error occurs? What am I missing here?

Comment: You need to handle errors better, perhaps with a try catch.  Also, a description of the error and code you've written would be helpful as well.

Comment: also, in some cases there is an `'error'` event that can be handled. e.g., the code sample here: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback

Comment: That means if an unhandled error is thrown, then the server goes down in MEAN stack? In reality, even if you handle errors properly, some errors might be thrown in a big application at some time!

Comment: Ask yourself: what should your app do when it gets an _unexpected_ error? By definition, it's something the developer didn't anticipate on and therefore the chance of the app ending up in an undefined state is large. What _else_ besides crashing should it do? FWIW, check out [`pm2`](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) for a process manager that will keep an eye out.

Comment: Well, in Java EE world, if errors thrown, that specific part will not function. But the other parts will function properly. The server will never go down due to application errors.

Comment: In MEAN stack, the server itself is created using application code, is it the reason the server goes down due to app errors? Is it a downside of MEAN stack?

Comment: It's a little outdated but good start here: https://www.joyent.com/developers/node/design/errors. TL;DR fix all programmer errors, handle all operational errors gracefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one solution that I have seen being used in production to ensure that a node program is always running (even after server restarts).

Use Forever (https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever). You can run it through code or through command line.

```
 $ [sudo] npm install forever -g
 forever start app.js
```

Where app.js has the code for instantiating the web server (in the MEAN stack it's the express initialization).

Comment: Please add reason for down voting.

Comment: I do not understand why people down-vote this answer!!

Answer (score 1):

If an unhandled error bubbles to the top of the stack without being caught, crashing is the intended behavior. An unhandled exception means that your app is in an undefined state.

Think of it this way. If you lose control of your car and drive off the road, the best thing to do is to slam on the brakes and stop (AKA a controlled program *crash* or *halt*) rather than continue blindly blundering through foliage, flower beds, backyards, swimming pools, toddlers, and whatever other obstacles may be in the way.

I'd recommend using a tool like [forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) to run your app in production, which will monitor and restart your app when it crashes. This sort of thing is standard practice. Obviously you don't want it to crash, and you should handle errors in context where you know how to recover from them. And some frameworks do a better job than others of handling errors smoothly without crashing. Restarting the process is mainly best for things that catch you completely off guard. Checkout this for more error handling tips:

https://www.joyent.com/developers/node/design/errors

Comment: To extend the analogy: Just using forever without ensuring that you're properly handing errors first would be like knowing that your brake cables are cut and just getting back in the car and driving it again every time you crash.

Comment: I kind of agree/disagree. A "crash" in this sense is more of a controlled stop, so in that sense your emergency brake cables are never cut, no matter how shitty your error handling is. An emergency stop/crash is always better than continuing in an undefined state. Good error handling only improves the situation from there.

Answer (score 0):

The issue mentioned by you is the point you need to keep in your mind while you develop applications. Because the way of handling errors is the thing that you can't skip. There are a few useful solutions (just a small part of the whole 'Error Handling' World) you can use in order to save your applications.

But lets start from your issue. As you have already such situation, I can recommend you integrating node domain module into your application, so it will not crash in case of such exceptions. Please refer to the link below:

https://nodejs.org/api/domain.html

You may wrap your server creation and catch all the unhandled exceptions.

Example:

```
var domain = require('domain').create();

domain.on('error', function(err){
  //track error into your log file
  //do something else with error (send message to admin, send error response etc. )
});

domain.run(function(){
  //run http server here
});
```

Here you may find good example as well:

https://engineering.gosquared.com/error-handling-using-domains-node-js

As for error handling solutions I can recommend you keeping the following rules:

- use domain to catch exceptions
- use node eventemitter to event and catch exceptions
- always think about possible situations when you handle results of functions
- develop single strategy of error handling (throw error/return error/send error to user etc.)
- use try catch block to safe code blocks from unhandled exceptions

There are much more solutions you can find.

Please see the links I recommend you to check:

- https://www.joyent.com/developers/node/design/errors
- http://derickbailey.com/2014/09/06/proper-error-handling-in-expressjs-route-handlers/
- http://expressjs.com/guide/error-handling.html
- http://shapeshed.com/uncaught-exceptions-in-node/